Dual-unitary Circuits in Measurement-based quantum computation
Could somebody please explain what unitary dual circuits are in simple terms? What makes these circuits being unitary in both time and space useful for quantum computations? Also, I am trying to understand how they are useful in measurement-based quantum computation as described in this paper https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2209.06191. I did not get how the physical time becomes virtual space, and physical space becomes virtual time in figure-1 of this paper. How this interchangeability helps in preserving the initial state?

TL,DR:
Dual-unitary circuits are circuits built out of 2-qudit gates that are unitary in two directions; in time, as usual, and also in space, under a mathematical regrouping of the legs of the gate into inputs and outputs along space-like slices, or equivalently, a diagrammatic rotation of the gate through 90 degrees. They have primarily been of interest for many-body physicists studying quantum chaos; applications to quantum computing have been less of a focus, though some nice examples are starting to be discovered. It makes sense that they may have applications to MBQC, as the measurements in MBQC protocols often result in an effective flow of information - a computation - in the spatial direction of the circuit; dual-unitary circuits, by virtue of being unitary in space, also can be thought of enacting a logical quantum computation in the spatial direction of the circuit. This allows for the construction of MBQC protocols with favourable resource requirements, as detailed in the paper you referenced. To understand how the roles of space and time can be swapped around in their circuit, I would recommend reading Appendix A of the paper, and focussing on the bulk of the circuit (as opposed to the qubits/gates near to the boundary/edge). You should see that circuit reads exactly the same when rotated around 90 degrees (swapping the roles of space and time), though you do need to slide the $S$ gates around a bit (using some commutation properties detailed in the paper) in order to get the full picture.

Okay, now for the full answer. You have a few questions, so I'll try to answer them in order.

What is a dual-unitary circuit?

Simply put, a dual-unitary circuit is a quantum circuit in which all of the gates are dual-unitary. A dual-unitary gate is a two qubit, or more generally two qudit (it just needs to act on two quantum systems, each of some dimension $d$), gate, which is unitary in two directions. This property is best illustrated diagrammatically. Firstly, it must be unitary across this bipartition of the 4 wires coming out of the gate into input and output legs:

This is just the standard unitarity that all the gates in a quantum circuit must obey; remember that quantum dynamics is reversible (ignoring the presence of any noise or measurements), and so all the gates in a quantum circuit must be unitary in order to ensure the circuit is reversible too.
Dual-unitary gates additionally obey unitarity in space, which means they are unitary across this bipartition:

(N.B.: You could swap around the inputs and outputs across the bipartition (the same is true for the unitarity diagram above), putting the inputs on the left and the outputs on the right - it's all a bit arbitrary. I am just labelling them as shown here for pedagogical convenience)
Some people sometimes complain that the diagram above doesn't really look like unitarity in space, so another way to draw it is like this

where we have simply dragged the $U^{\dagger}$ gate around (as we have the freedom to do in tensor network notation; the way you position the tensors (read: gates, in this example) doesn't matter, only the way you connect them).
Additionally, we can also define the dual-gate, $\tilde{U}$ (which I sort of already referred ahead to, in the second diagram). This is a bit hand-wavey, but you can think about $\tilde{U}$ as the original unitary $U$ simply rotated around 90 degrees; this swaps around the roles of space and time, with $t$ becoming a new space-like direction - let's call it $\tilde{x}$ - and $x$ (the direction the qubits of the circuit are arranged in) becoming a new time-like direction - let's call it $\tilde{t}$ (I cover this more detail, on the level of the whole circuit, in answer to your 4th question (about how to understand Figure 1 of the paper) below). The dual-gate reproduces the evolution generated by $U$ in the spatial direction, and so will be unitary if (and only if) $U$ is dual-unitary.

I will refer you to the literature for non-diagrammatic definitions, such as in bra-ket notation, of dual-unitarity. A good place to start is https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.02140; Eqn. 5, in particular, may be helpful in aiding your understanding.
I realise you may like a bit more information on what dual-unitary circuits are beyond this basic definition, but I think it is best to answer that in response to your next question.

What makes them useful for quantum computation?

To be honest, the primary reason people are interested in dual-unitary circuits has nothing to do (at least directly) with quantum computation.
Dual-unitary circuits have attracted attention as they are an analytically tractable model of quantum chaos. What do I mean by that?
Well, quantum chaos is a little hard to explain, as we do not really have a concrete consensus on what it precisely means for a quantum system to be chaotic. There are, however, a number of probes - things that one can calculate or measure, for a given quantum system - that people have agreed are useful for studying whether a quantum system is chaotic. In dual-unitary circuits we can exactly calculate a lot of these measures by hand - and doing so reveals them (except for some fine-tuned exceptions) to be maximally chaotic (arXiv:2012.12254).
Typically, being able to analytically study quantum systems in this way relies on the presence of a special property called integrability, which is sort of the exact opposite of chaos. In dual-unitary circuits, we instead have a very chaotic system which we can study analytically, without the need for integrability. As understanding quantum chaos is still a very big open problem in many-body physics, they have hence attracted a lot of interest from people working in this field.
This is not to say that they don't have any utility for quantum computation; it is just that this has not been the focus of studies on them, and so examples of this kind are perhaps limited. The paper you reference is one notable example. They have been shown more recently to  have some fairly nice properties from the perspective of classical shadow tomography (arXiv:2404.01068).
They also have found some use as a benchmark - being that we can study them classically - for experiments on nascent quantum devices; see arXiv:2105.09324  from Honeywell (now Quantinuum), and the Nature 'quantum utility' paper from IBM. Both use dual-unitary circuits to benchmark their experiments on their quantum processors.
Also, the idea of thinking about circuits in the spatial direction is starting to find some applicability more generally. If you take a regular quantum circuit, which generically won't be dual-unitary, you can still think about what kind of evolution it performs in the spatial direction of the system; it is just that this evolution might be non-unitary. In other words, the spatial circuit has some effective noise or measurements, when the original circuit (in the usual time direction) is not dual-unitary. Some researchers have started to think about practical protocols that make use of this; if you're clever about it, you can use a unitary circuit to simulate non-unitary dynamics and vice-versa. See arXiv:2103.06873 and arXiv:2103.06356.
Other interesting applications may be out there - the model is still quite young, relatively speaking. The first papers appeared only a bit over 5 years ago, and lots of work is still going on regarding them. For now, however, they are mostly of interest from a many-body physics perspective, aside from the few examples I have noted above (and perhaps some others I have missed out - I do not claim that this list is exhaustive).

How are they useful in measurement-based quantum computation?

As far as I am aware, the paper you reference is the only paper so far that specifically studies dual-unitaries in the context of MBQC, and so ultimately it is itself the best place for you to find answers to this question. Nonetheless, I'll try my best to summarise its findings here.
The key starting point is that in MBQC there is already a notion of spatial computation; the measurements one performs at the end of the circuit can be thought of as affecting an effective computation, or flow of information, in the spatial direction of the circuit. I'm not an expert in MBQC so am not best placed to give an explanation of this, but you can see it popping up in certain places in the literature, for example in https://journals.aps.org/pra/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevA.68.022312 (see Section 3F).
Of course, one would then want to think about ways to make sure this computation in the spatial direction is unitary; we want it to be a quantum computation, after all. Dual-unitary circuits naturally have the property of spatial unitarity, so maybe it makes sense to consider them for MBQC. In the paper, the authors show that dual-unitary circuits can prepare resource states for MBQC and that appropriate measurements of these states can then enact universal computation in the spatial direction. Moreover, this spatial computation can be directly read off by simply looking at the dual-unitarity circuit in the dual, spatial direction. Their protocol also has some nice advantages from a resources standpoint, requiring a depth-$k$ 1D circuit and $N$ single-qubit measurements to simulate a depth-$N$ circuit on $k$ qubits, as opposed to typical MBQC protocols which require $Nk$ measurements and 2D geometries to do the same.

How does the physical/virtual space become virtual/physical time in Fig.1 of the reference paper?

Let's forget about the specific circuit the authors are considering in that paper for a moment, and think about this more abstractly.
Think about a depth-$t$ circuit acting on $N$ qubits. Let's label the qubits with some position $x$ (usually we use integers, so $x = 0,1,2,...N-1$) - this is your physical space.
Now just think about one of those $N$ qubits, say the qubit at $x=0$. Think about the $t+1$ copies of that qubit at each instance of time; one copy corresponding to the qubit before the 1st layer is applied, another to the qubit after the 1st layer is applied, another copy after the 2nd layer, and so on up until all $t$ layers of the circuit have been applied. These copies of that qubit - some space-like slice of the circuit, to use physics talk - form your new virtual space.
Now think about doing the same process for the $t+1$ copies of the qubit at position $x=1$, neighbouring our $x=0$ qubit. This gives us another space-like slice of the system. We should be able to write down some linear map that takes states on our $x=0$ space-slice - our new, virtual space - as input, and outputs states on the $x=1$ space-slice - it might be horrible, it might not be unitary or interpretable as a circuit (and so working with pure states might not be enough), but it should exist. By doing this, however, we are evolving our $t+1$ qubits - our virtual space - in the original spatial direction of the system, from $x=0$ to $x=1$. We could keep doing this, all the way up until $x=N-1$. Our physical space has become our virtual time - the direction we are evolving our virtual qubits in.
Formally, it would maybe be best to think about associating a label $x$ and a label $t$ to each qubit - some Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_{x,t} = \mathbb{C}^2$ - at each point in space and time. Our original circuit would act on the tensor product Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_{t=0} = \mathcal{H}_{0,0} \otimes \mathcal{H}_{1,0} \otimes ... \otimes \mathcal{H}_{N-1,0}$ representing our physical space, mapping it after the first layer to $\mathcal{H}_{t=1} = \mathcal{H}_{0,1} \otimes \mathcal{H}_{1,1} \otimes ... \otimes \mathcal{H}_{N-1,1}$, and so on up to $\mathcal{H}_{t=t} = \mathcal{H}_{0,t} \otimes \mathcal{H}_{1,t} \otimes ... \otimes \mathcal{H}_{N-1,t}$. Equivalently, we could have the tensor product Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_{x=0} = \mathcal{H}_{0,0} \otimes \mathcal{H}_{0,1} \otimes ... \otimes \mathcal{H}_{0,t}$ representing our virtual space, which gets mapped to $\mathcal{H}_{x=1} = \mathcal{H}_{1,0} \otimes \mathcal{H}_{1,1} \otimes ... \otimes \mathcal{H}_{1,t}$, and so on up to $\mathcal{H}_{x=N-1} = \mathcal{H}_{N-1,0} \otimes \mathcal{H}_{N-1,1} \otimes ... \otimes \mathcal{H}_{N-1,t}$.
A dual-unitary circuit is the special case where the maps mapping each copy of the virtual space into the next are also unitary, and so each map can be thought of as a layer of quantum gates. Together, they will then form a depth-$N$ quantum circuit acting on the $t+1$ qubits of our virtual space.
The particular dual-unitary gate the authors choose to build the circuit out of in the paper you reference has the nice, additional property that it is self-dual; it is not only unitary in the spatial direction, but is in fact completely invariant under switching the roles of space and time - it enacts the same unitary in both the space and time directions. This is evident in the diagrams the authors provide in Appendix A, with the only subtle point being that the $S$ gates they include in the diagrams can be slid past the delta tensors (where the legs in the diagrams cross), as they are diagonal in the computational basis (this is explained in the text).

Things get a little fuzzy around the boundary of the circuit, but if you look at the bulk hopefully it should be clear (once you understand the commutation of the $S$ gates with the CZ gates/delta tensors) that the circuit looks exactly the same if you were to rotate it around 90 degrees, swapping the roles of time and space.

How does this interchangeability help in preserving the initial state?

I'm not sure I completely understand your question here, apologies. In the MBQC paper you're referencing, they start with a specific, fixed input state; each qubit is initialised in the plus state, $|+\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle$. They then show the dual-unitary circuit they consider generates resource states for MBQC from this initial state. Generating these resources states is the goal; not preserving the initial state in any way. At least as far as I understand it.
In general, the utility of dual-unitary circuits for 'preserving' quantum information (taking a fairly liberal interpretation of your question) is, I would say, unclear. There are no clear links to error correction or quantum memory dynamics, that I am aware of. The only good connection I can think of (again, perhaps I am missing some others), is this paper which studies the Hayden-Preskill decoding problem in various unitary circuit models (including DUCs): https://arxiv.org/pdf/2312.03838. Dual-unitaries do have some pretty nice information processing properties in the context of this problem, owing to the fact that they scramble quantum information (and generate entanglement) remarkably well (they are maximally chaotic, after all).

Sorry some papers aren't linked - I can only post 8 links apparently. Hope this helps, nonetheless.

Thank you for the detailed answer!

Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange!

@EmilioPisanty Thanks!
